# MongoDB: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path

Tags: mongodb

I just upgraded to Mongo 2.6.1 and one update statement that was working before is not returning an error. The update statement is:

```
db.post.update( { 'answers.comments.name': 'jeff' },
    { '$set': {
        'answers.$.comments.$.name': 'joe'
    }},
    { multi: true }
)
```

The error I get is:

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 2,
        "errmsg" : "Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'answers.$.comments.$.createUsername'"
    }
})
```

When I update an element just one level deep instead of two (i.e. `answers.$.name` instead of `answers.$.comments.$.name`), it works fine. If I downgrade my mongo instance below 2.6, it also  works fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The positional operator can be used only once in a query. This is a limitation, there is an open ticket for improvement: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

Comment: You are correct that this is an issue with the current version of MongoDB (2.6.1) and the open ticket you specify is to address the issue. As a workaround, however, I actually got this to work in Mongo 2.4.10. I have downgraded for now until they fix this issue.

Comment: Is this ever got fixed, getting this error in v3.2.3

Answer (score 24):

Use `arrayFilters`.

> MongoDB 3.5.12 extends all update modifiers to apply to all array
>   elements or all array elements that match a predicate, specified in a
>   new update option arrayFilters. This syntax also supports nested array
>   elements.

Let us assume a scenario-

```
"access": {
    "projects": [{
        "projectId": ObjectId(...),
        "milestones": [{
            "milestoneId": ObjectId(...),
            "pulses": [{
                "pulseId": ObjectId(...)
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Now if you want to add a *pulse* to a *milestone* which exists inside a *project*

```
db.users.updateOne({
    "_id": ObjectId(userId)
}, {
    "$push": {
        "access.projects.$[i].milestones.$[j].pulses": ObjectId(pulseId)
    }
}, {
    arrayFilters: [{
        "i.projectId": ObjectId(projectId)
    }, {
        "j.milestoneId": ObjectId(milestoneId)
    }]
})
```

For **PyMongo**, use arrayFilters like this-

```
db.users.update_one({
    "_id": ObjectId(userId)
}, {
    "$push": {
        "access.projects.$[i].milestones.$[j].pulses": ObjectId(pulseId)
    }
}, array_filters = [{
        "i.projectId": ObjectId(projectId)
}, {
        "j.milestoneId": ObjectId(milestoneId)
}])
```

Also,

> Each array filter must be a predicate over a document with a single
>   field name. Each array filter must be used in the update expression,
>   and each array filter identifier $[] must have a corresponding
>   array filter.  must begin with a lowercase letter and not contain
>   any special characters. There must not be two array filters with the
>   same field name.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

Comment: very nice answer,   one short question, __how to ensure that only one item in $[i] are matched__?              Assume that there are multiple `i` that satisfy `"i.projectId": ObjectId(projectId)` , since the original purpose of using `$` is because it matches one item in an array only.

Answer (score 21):

You **CAN** do this, you just need Mongo 3.6! Instead of redesigning your database, you could use the Array Filters feature in Mongo 3.6, which can be found here:

https://thecodebarbarian.com/a-nodejs-perspective-on-mongodb-36-array-filters

The beauty of this is that you can bind all matches in an array to a variable, and then reference that variable later. Here is the prime example from the link above:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned; more than one positional elements not supported for now. You may update with mongodb **cursor.forEach()** method.

```
db.post
  .find({"answers.comments.name": "jeff"})
  .forEach(function(post) {
    if (post.answers) {
      post.answers.forEach(function(answer) {
        if (answer.comments) {
          answer.comments.forEach(function(comment) {
            if (comment.name === "jeff") {
              comment.name = "joe";
            }
          });
        }
      });

      db.post.save(post);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
    db.post.update(
    { 'answers.comments.name': 'jeff' },
    { '$set': {
        'answers.$[i].comments.$.name': 'joe'
    }},
    {arrayFilters: [ { "i.comments.name": { $eq: 'jeff' } } ]}
)
```

check path after `answers` for get key path right

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue for the as array inside Array update require much performance impact. So, mongo db doest not support it. Redesign your database as shown in the given link below.

https://pythonolyk.wordpress.com/2016/01/17/mongodb-update-nested-array-using-positional-operator/

Answer (score -4):

```
db.post.update( { 'answers.comments.name': 'jeff' },
    { '$set': {
        'answers.$.comments.$.name': 'joe'
    }},
    { multi: true }
)
```

Answer is

```
db.post.update( { 'answers.comments.name': 'jeff' },
    { '$set': {
        'answers.0.comments.1.name': 'joe'
    }},
    { multi: true }
)
```

Comment: How do you know its at position zero?
answers.0.comments.1.name': 'joe'

Comment: Shouldn't it be: {$set: {'answers.0.comments.0.name': joe'}} ...  The item found in arrays will always be at position 0, because it is always going to be just one: the one that matches the query criteria ...

Comment: @ManuelRivera __Why__ The item found in arrays will always be at position 0?       I don't think it is making sense.

Comment: Maybe at that time I was thinking the operation was going to find just one item and that will be the only one in the array. However, now I can see that was not a correct assumption.