# Updating Nested subdocument using id mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

> I need to edit my prescriptions quantity .Here is my sample code.

```
collection.update(
{ "_id" : 1,"medications._id" : 23,"medications.prescriptions._id":77 },
{ $set : { "medications.$0.prescriptions.$1.quantity" : 30 } },
false,
true
)
```

> How to edit this. It does not shown any error .

Comment: try medications.$.prescriptions.$.quantity

Comment: Hi chirag . i got the following error "Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'medications.$.prescriptions.$.quantity'".

Answer (score 0):

**you can use only one positional operator**

And see this documentation:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: Hi chirag . i got the following error "Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'medications.$.prescriptions.$.quantity'".

Comment: can you provide your json data..?

Comment: sure. below is my json  data.
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ab0f1627687f811900000d"),
    "title" : "Primary",
    "bgimage" : "Screenshot from 2016-05-25 10:56:16.png"
    "medications" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57ab0f2227687f811900000e"),
            "title" : "Secondary"
            "prescriptions" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("57ab0f3227687f811900000f"),
                    "title" : "Tertiary",
                    "description" : "Desc"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}

Comment: in your collection.update, try medications[0]._id and medications[0].prescriptions[0]._id

Comment: you asked me to change  medication index (i.e [0] ) . But same error only occurring  "Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path "

Comment: you can use only one positional operator. refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046470/mongodb-too-many-positional-i-e-elements-found-in-path

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can follow a more `easy to understand` way.

```
var updateData = {
    medications.prescriptions.quantity: 0
}

collection.update({ "_id" : 1,"medications._id" : 23,"medications.prescriptions._id":77 }, updateData, function(err, response){
    if(err){
        res.json(err);
    }
    //your success handler
});
```

Comment: hi Ajitej , It erases my subdocuments , and set medications prescription as 0.

Comment: I have edited the answer a little bit and as per my assumption your subdocument looks like `medications: {prescriptions: {quantity: //value }}`

Comment: it throws "Unexpected token . " on your edited code above

Comment: bro, can you share the model and explain a little bit more in detail what is your desired response!

Comment: Below is my json data.
"_id" : 54, 
 "title" : "p1", 
    "medications" : [
        {
            "_id" : 57, 
            "title" : "S1", 
            "prescriptions" : [
                {
                    "_id" : 57a, 
                    "title" : "T1", 
                    "description" : "T1"
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : 4507, 
                    "title" : "T12", 
                    "description" : "T12121212"
                }
            ]
        },
Here i want to edit my prescription details . Is it OK for you

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue for the as array inside Array update require much performance impact. So, mongo db doest not support it. Redesign your database as shown in the given link below.

https://pythonolyk.wordpress.com/2016/01/17/mongodb-update-nested-array-using-positional-operator/