# mongodb insert parameter to object array of object array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, set, push

I'm new to this site and mongodb.

I have a problem with inserting mongodb data looks like below.

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("jsjejrekjwrjkl"),
"bind":[
    {
        "properties":[
            {
                "a":1
            },
            {
                "a":1
            },
        ],
        "somewhat":"somevalue"
    },
    {
        "properties":[
            {
                "a":1
            },
            {
                "a":1
            },
        ],
        "somewhat":"somevalue"
    }
]
}
```

and what I want to do on this data is like below

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("jsjejrekjwrjkl"),
"bind":[
    {
        "properties":[
            {
                "a":1,
                "b":2
            },
            {
                "a":1,
                "b":2
            },
        ],
        "somewhat":"somevalue"
    },
    {
        "properties":[
            {
                "a":1,
                "b":2
            },
            {
                "a":1,
                "b":2
            },
        ],
        "somewhat":"somevalue"
    }
]
}
```

I've searched hard and coudln't get any appropriate ways of solving this.

Every method that I tried like $push, $set, $elemMatch and some other methods was useless...

I'm looking for good way of inserting a key value pair into every array of object array like the example.

I hope some of you help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is achievable using a single update query, where there is nested array. Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046470/mongodb-too-many-positional-i-e-elements-found-in-path)

However, you can achieve by fetching the data, manipulating it and then saving it back, but I don't think a single query can achieve that.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! As you mentioned I realized that It is really hard to be archived using single query. I decided to insert data using script like node, python.