# How to add element to nested array in mongo 3.4 using php

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to push array element into inner array of the following document structure

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("599558a4a331801fe264bbb3"),
"zone" : "asia",
"country_list" : [
    {
        "country_name" : "india",
        "state_list" : [
            {
                "state_name" : "kerala"
            },
            {
                "state_name" : "tamilnadu"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "country_name" : "pak",
        "state_list" : [
            {
                "state_name" : "ins"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

the structure after update i want to be as

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("599558a4a331801fe264bbb3"),
"zone" : "asia",
"country_list" : [
    {
        "country_name" : "india",
        "state_list" : [
            {
                "state_name" : "kerala",
                "city_list" : [
                          {
                            "cityname" : "tvm"
                          },
                          {
                            "cityname" : "kchi"
                          },
                 ]
            },
            {
                "state_name" : "tamilnadu"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "country_name" : "pak",
        "state_list" : [
            {
                "state_name" : "ins"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

However when I try the following code

```
$result     = $this->collection->findOneAndUpdate(array(
        "country_list.state_list.state_name"=>$this->getState()
    ), array(
        '$push'=>array("country_list.state_list.$.city_list"=>array("city_name"=>$this->getCity()))
    ));
```

I get the error

Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException: cannot use the part (country_list of country_list.state_list.0.city_list) to traverse the element ({country_list: [ { country_name: "india", state_list: [ { state_name: "kerala" }, { state_name: "tamilnadu" } ] }, { country_name: "pak", state_list: [ { state_name: "ins" } ] } ]})

I am using mongo 3.4 and php 7

Comment: You might want to check the various answers here because I think you will need to use a completely different approach at the moment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046470/mongodb-too-many-positional-i-e-elements-found-in-path

Answer (score 0):

**Reason of the Error**: `country_list` is an array so you have to use positional operator with $set or $push statement.

**Solution:** In MongoDB 3.4, positional operator ($) can be used only once so what you want cannot be achieved with positional operator. You need to loop through in the client code (PHP), prepare the updated document and then collection update.

FYI - In 3.6, positional operator is improved so you can use that after upgrading. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831