# What is the solution to "Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path"?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have searched over the web for this issue, the conclusion where I have reached is that it is a bug in the latest version of mongo as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046470/mongodb-too-many-positional-i-e-elements-found-in-path) and [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14164)

The problem is that the structure of the object is as following:

```
{
"_id": 2,
"status": 0,
"details": [{
    "id": 2,
    "category": "A",
    "obj": {
        "apple": 5,
        "banana": 2,
        "cherry": 10
    },
    "members": [{
            "id": 3,
            "category": "A",
            "obj": {
                "apple": 5,
                "banana": 2,
                "cherry": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "category": "A",
            "obj": {
                "apple": 5,
                "banana": 2,
                "cherry": 10
            }
        }
    ]
  }]
}
```

which I am using everywhere in my project which is almost ready. But now the requirement is to update the `obj` inside the `members` object. For which I tried

```
cond  := bson.M{ "$and": []bson.M{ bson.M{"details":bson.M{ "$elemMatch": bson.M{ "category": "A"} } }, bson.M{"status":0} } }
query := bson.M{ "$set": bson.M{ "details.$.members.$.obj.guava":15 } }
_, err := models.DbUpdateAll(Collection, cond, query)
```

But it is not working. Do I need to change the whole structure of the document by maintaining the array in different collection and passing reference to this object? It will be really a bad idea as for now where the project stands.... Isn't there any easy solution?

Comment: Please define _"But it is not working."_ An error is returned? Bad or no documents get updated? Also what version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: What is your mongo server version ?

Comment: Hi @icza, It is throwing the error "Too many positional arguments found in the path". The version of my mongodb is "3.4.10".

Comment: @Veeram, The version is "3.4.10"

Comment: The bug you've referenced has been fixed in 3.6 release. Can you update to latest 3.6.1 and try `db.collection_name.update({"status": 0, "details.category":"A"}, {"$set": "details.$[d].members.$[].obj.guava":15}, {"arrayFilters":[{"d.category":"A"}]})`. Hopefully you can transform into go.

Comment: @Veeram, Okay let me check. Thanks! :)

Comment: I was working on an issue like this and ended up using arrayFilters. My solution is posted in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48594481/selecting-and-updating-a-nested-object-by-its-objectid-in-mongoose-js/48604602#48604602