# Update nested object after matching id of main document and nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a following structure of mongo document

```
{
    "registrationDate": "2020-06-09T18:15:00.000Z",
    "_id": "5ee6dd003a97c93c6436349c",
    "ofSite": "5ee19fe085d70733243c3309",
    "patientID": "NGH-123",
    "neocareID": "",
    "babyName": "Joey",
    "motherName": "Phoebe",
    "dateOfBirth": "2020-06-08T18:15:00.000Z",
    "babySex": "Female",
    "birthType": "Single",
    "patientType": "Referred",
    "mobileNumber": "9802824412",
    "mobileOf": "Family Member",
    "linkedFCHV": "Racheal",
    "FCHVmobile": "9876225420",
    "address": "Holloywood",
    "examinations": [
        {
            "ODExam": {
                "plusODExam": "No",
                "zoneODExam": "I",
                "ropODExam": "No",
                "ropODStage": 1,
                "categoryOD": "None",
                "apROPOD": "Yes"
            },
            "OSExam": {
                "plusOSExam": "No",
                "zoneOSExam": "I",
                "ropOSExam": "Yes",
                "ropOSStage": 1,
                "categoryOS": "None",
                "apROPOS": "Yes"
            },
            "FindingFollowUp": {
                "ropFindings": "All Good so far",
                "followUpPlan": "Follow up in next month",
                "nameOfExaminer": "Luzan",
                "followUpDate": "2020-07-07T18:15:00.000Z"
            },
            "_id": "5ee6dd793a97c93c6436349e",
            "examinationDate": "06/12/2020",
            "currentPMA": 5,
            "daysOfLife": 42,
            "currentWeight": 4500,
            "visitType": "First"
        },
        {
            "ODExam": {
                "plusODExam": "No",
                "zoneODExam": "I",
                "ropODExam": "No",
                "ropODStage": 1,
                "categoryOD": "None",
                "apROPOD": "Yes"
            },
            "OSExam": {
                "plusOSExam": "No",
                "zoneOSExam": "I",
                "ropOSExam": "Yes",
                "ropOSStage": 1,
                "categoryOS": "None",
                "apROPOS": "Yes"
            },
            "FindingFollowUp": {
                "ropFindings": "All Good so far",
                "followUpPlan": "Follow up in next month",
                "nameOfExaminer": "Luzan",
                "followUpDate": "2020-07-07T18:15:00.000Z"
            },
            "_id": "5ee6dd913a97c93c643634a0",
            "examinationDate": "06/12/2020",
            "currentPMA": 5,
            "currentWeight": 4500,
            "visitType": "First"
        },
        {
            "ODExam": {
                "plusODExam": "No",
                "zoneODExam": "I",
                "ropODExam": "No",
                "ropODStage": 1,
                "categoryOD": "None",
                "apROPOD": "Yes"
            },
            "OSExam": {
                "plusOSExam": "No",
                "zoneOSExam": "I",
                "ropOSExam": "Yes",
                "ropOSStage": 1,
                "categoryOS": "None",
                "apROPOS": "Yes"
            },
            "FindingFollowUp": {
                "ropFindings": "All Good so far",
                "followUpPlan": "Follow up in next month",
                "nameOfExaminer": "Luzan",
                "followUpDate": "2020-07-07T18:15:00.000Z"
            },
            "_id": "5ee6ddf13a97c93c643634a2",
            "examinationDate": "06/12/2020",
            "currentPMA": 5,
            "currentWeight": 4500,
            "visitType": "First"
        },
        {
            "ODExam": {
                "plusODExam": "No",
                "zoneODExam": "I",
                "ropODExam": "No",
                "ropODStage": 1,
                "categoryOD": "None",
                "apROPOD": "Yes"
            },
            "OSExam": {
                "plusOSExam": "No",
                "zoneOSExam": "I",
                "ropOSExam": "Yes",
                "ropOSStage": 1,
                "categoryOS": "None",
                "apROPOS": "Yes"
            },
            "FindingFollowUp": {
                "ropFindings": "All Good so far",
                "followUpPlan": "Follow up in next month",
                "nameOfExaminer": "Luzan",
                "followUpDate": "2020-07-07T18:15:00.000Z"
            },
            "_id": "5ee6de093a97c93c643634a4",
            "examinationDate": "06/12/2020",
            "currentPMA": 5,
            "currentWeight": 4500,
            "visitType": "First"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 4
}
```

Let me tell you what I am trying to do here. This is my route

```
adminRoutes.post(
  '/examination/:patientID/:examID',
  userController.ensureAuthenticated,
  examController.findOneAndUpdate
)
```

I am passing `_id` of patient as `:patientID` (document) and `_id` of nested examinations object as `:examID`, my objective is to update the examination of patient by matching examination id.
This is my controller.

```
/**
 * POST /admin/examination/:patientID/:examID
 **/
exports.findOneAndUpdate = function (req, res) {
  const query = { examinations: { $elemMatch: { _id: new ObjectId(req.params.examID) } } }
  const update = {
    $set: {
      examinationDate: req.body.examinationDate,
      daysOfLife: req.body.daysOfLife,
      currentPMA: req.body.currentPMA,
      currentWeight: req.body.currentWeight,
      visitType: req.body.visitType,
      ODExam: {
        plusODExam: req.body.plusODExam,
        zoneODExam: req.body.zoneODExam,
        ropODExam: req.body.ropODExam,
        ropODStage: req.body.ropODStage,
        categoryOD: req.body.categoryOD,
        apROPOD: req.body.apROPOD
      },
      OSExam: {
        plusOSExam: req.body.ropOSExam,
        zoneOSExam: req.body.zoneOSExam,
        ropOSExam: req.body.ropOSExam,
        ropOSStage: req.body.ropOSStage,
        categoryOS: req.body.categoryOS,
        apROPOS: req.body.apROPOS
      },
      FindingFollowUp: {
        ropFindings: req.body.ropFindings,
        followUpPlan: req.body.followUpPlan,
        nameOfExaminer: req.body.nameOfExaminer,
        followUpDate: req.body.followUpDate
      }
    }
  }
  const options = { arrayFilters: [{ 'examinations._id': new ObjectId(req.params.examID) }] }
  Patient.updateOne(query, update, options, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      res.send(err)
    } else {
      console.log(result)
      res.send(result)
    }
  })
}
```

I took reference from [Selecting and updating a nested object by it's ObjectId in Mongoose.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48604602/1939163). But I am getting an error.

```
MongoError: The array filter for identifier 'examinations' was not used in the update { $set: { daysOfLife: 45 } }
```

Am I doing it worng, what might be an effective way to update a single examination in this case. And is this a proper way to update only the data what has been changed? Thank you for your time reading this.

Update [Solved].
I fixed it with the help of comment from @thammada.ts . All thanks to him. Changed my update as:

```
const update = {
    $set: {
      'examinations.$[exam].examinationDate': req.body.examinationDate,
      'examinations.$[exam].daysOfLife': req.body.daysOfLife,
      'examinations.$[exam].currentPMA': req.body.currentPMA,
      'examinations.$[exam].currentWeight': req.body.currentWeight,
      'examinations.$[exam].visitType': req.body.visitType,
      'examinations.$[exam].ODExam': {
        plusODExam: req.body.plusODExam,
        zoneODExam: req.body.zoneODExam,
        ropODExam: req.body.ropODExam,
        ropODStage: req.body.ropODStage,
        categoryOD: req.body.categoryOD,
        apROPOD: req.body.apROPOD
      },
      'examinations.$[exam].OSExam': {
        plusOSExam: req.body.ropOSExam,
        zoneOSExam: req.body.zoneOSExam,
        ropOSExam: req.body.ropOSExam,
        ropOSStage: req.body.ropOSStage,
        categoryOS: req.body.categoryOS,
        apROPOS: req.body.apROPOS
      },
      'examinations.$[exam].FindingFollowUp': {
        ropFindings: req.body.ropFindings,
        followUpPlan: req.body.followUpPlan,
        nameOfExaminer: req.body.nameOfExaminer,
        followUpDate: req.body.followUpDate
      }
    }
  }
```

and used `'exam.id'` on arrayFilters.

Comment: If you are using `examinations` in your `arrayFilters`, you will have to specify `examinations[examinations]` in your `update`. Maybe you should rename to `examinations[exam]` and `exam._id` to avoid confusion

Comment: @thammada.ts thanks for your time, can you please share me how I should do it.

Comment: @thammada.ts I got it. Thanks so much.

Comment: I have posted an answer nonetheless, I didn't see your update on the question :). Also added some tips on the query part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your `update` and `options` as follows

```
/*
Keep in mind that this will replace the whole element,
if you have other fields not included in the update, they will be removed.
To update new fields without replacing the element,
you have to specify all the fields like this

{
  $set: {
...
    "examinations.$[exam].examinationDate": req.body.examinationDate,
    "examinations.$[exam].daysOfLife": req.body.daysOfLife,

...
    "examinations.$[exam].ODExam.plusODExam": req.body.plusODExam,
    "examinations.$[exam].ODExam.zoneODExam": req.body.zoneODExam
...
  }
}
*/
const update = {
  $set: {
    "examinations.$[exam]": {
      _id: new ObjectId(req.params.examID),
      examinationDate: req.body.examinationDate,
      daysOfLife: req.body.daysOfLife,
      currentPMA: req.body.currentPMA,
      currentWeight: req.body.currentWeight,
      visitType: req.body.visitType,
      ODExam: {
        plusODExam: req.body.plusODExam,
        zoneODExam: req.body.zoneODExam,
        ropODExam: req.body.ropODExam,
        ropODStage: req.body.ropODStage,
        categoryOD: req.body.categoryOD,
        apROPOD: req.body.apROPOD
      },
      OSExam: {
        plusOSExam: req.body.ropOSExam,
        zoneOSExam: req.body.zoneOSExam,
        ropOSExam: req.body.ropOSExam,
        ropOSStage: req.body.ropOSStage,
        categoryOS: req.body.categoryOS,
        apROPOS: req.body.apROPOS
      },
      FindingFollowUp: {
        ropFindings: req.body.ropFindings,
        followUpPlan: req.body.followUpPlan,
        nameOfExaminer: req.body.nameOfExaminer,
        followUpDate: req.body.followUpDate
      }
    }
  }
}
const options = {
  arrayFilters: [{ 'exam._id': new ObjectId(req.params.examID) }]
}
```

Tip: you don't really have to do `$elemMatch` in your query. You can do

```
const query = { "examinations._id": new ObjectId(req.params.examID) }
```

Or to make sure it's updating the correct patient

```
const query = {
  "_id": new ObjectId(req.params.patientID),
  "examinations._id": new ObjectId(req.params.examID)
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why but following this answer, the _id of examination was changed.

Comment: Oh, because we are pushing a whole new document, see my explanation in the comment at the beginning of the code. I'll add the same _id back