# Updating Field in a Nested Subdocument MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nested, subdocument

I'm trying to update the IsActive flag inside the function object, however, it is deeply nested inside the Companies and Factories Objects. Trying to use $ is no use, as it does not work with deeply nested subdocuments. Has anyone found a way to work with this???I expect the IsActive flag to be modified, as right now it can only be reached. I've tried:

- $$
- List item
- Placing the $ at various points i.e. Factories.Functions.$.IsActive
  -Concatenating in functionIds

```
{function deleteFunction(companyId, factoryId, functionId) {
    return Companies.update({
        "CompanyId": companyId,
        "Factories.FactoryId": factoryId,
        "Factories.Functions.FunctionId": functionId,
    }, {"$set": {"Factories.$.Functions.IsActive": false}}
    ).then(function (result)  {
        console.log("Reached", result);
        return result
    }).catch(function (err) {
        logger.log(err);
    });
}}

let functionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    FunctionId: Number,
    Name: String,
    ADGroup: String,
    IsActive: Boolean,
    DateCreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    DateModified: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

let factorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    FactoryId: Number,
    Name: String,
    ADGroup: String,
    IsActive: Boolean,
    DateCreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    DateModified: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    Functions: [functionsSchema]
});

let companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    CompanyId: Number,
    Name: String,
    IsActive: Boolean,
    DateCreated: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    DateModified: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    Employees: [employeeSchema],
    Factories: [factorySchema]

});
```

Comment: Please add the schema definition.

Comment: Added it there now

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41619030/3284355

Comment: There's also a way to use arrayFilters but i have no experience with that https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/#update-command-arrayfilters